# What benefits does a PPA offer that a .deb or installing from the standard repositories doesn't?

Tags: ppa

I know that PPAs can be dangerous.

But if they were 100% bad, surely nobody would use them - and it wouldn't be so easy to add them onto Ubuntu and elementary OS?

So what are the benefits of a PPA over a `.deb` file or installing from the standard repositories?

Answer (score 3):

The fact that there is no distinguishable difference between installing software through trusted repositories, such as the main repository, and then installing software through a PPA (GUI and CLI)

The main benefit you *may* get is, **latest and up to date** packages.

Software Center(repositories)  *may* not always contain newer version of the package,  even though there are **higher versions** of the same package in developers' PPAs,  those will only be included in the **next release of the OS**.